# .jar conflict causes java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase exception

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, lucene, classloader

Because of different class versions in different **.jar** files I got this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, E:\neo4j
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:333)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
>       at neo4j_lucene.conflict_solver.ConfilctSolver.createDb(ConfilctSolver.java:55)
>       at neo4j_lucene.conflict_solver.ConfilctSolver.main(ConfilctSolver.java:35)

despite I'm using `ClassLoader` for solving this problem, but again I get same exception. Here is my code:

```
try {
        CustomClassLoader ccl = new CustomClassLoader();
        Object object;
        Class clas;
        clas = ccl
                .loadClass("org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory");

        object = clas.newInstance();

        graphDb = ((GraphDatabaseFactory) object)
                .newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Custom class loader code:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
private String jarFile = "C:/Users/RaufA/Desktop/test.jar"; // Path
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // jar
                                                                            // file
private Hashtable classes = new Hashtable(); // used to cache already
                                                // defined classes

public CustomClassLoader() {
    super(CustomClassLoader.class.getClassLoader()); // calls the parent
                                                        // class
                                                        // loader's
                                                        // constructor
}

public Class loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return findClass(className);
}

public Class findClass(String className) {
    byte classByte[];
    Class result = null;

    result = (Class) classes.get(className); // checks in cached classes
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }

    try {
        return findSystemClass(className);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);         
        JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry(className + ".class");     
        System.out.println(className+".class");
        InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nextValue = is.read();
        while (-1 != nextValue) {
            byteStream.write(nextValue);
            nextValue = is.read();
        }

        classByte = byteStream.toByteArray();
        result = defineClass(className, classByte, 0, classByte.length,
                null);
        classes.put(className, result);
        System.out.println(">>>>result: " + result);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

What else should I do?

Comment: Which classes do conflict? Some Neo4j and ? Which versions of both libraries are you using?

Comment: I solved problem by using `maven-shade-plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this project to eclipse -> https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar.
2. Use `mvn-install` and create `~SNAPSHOT.jar`
3. Add that `.jar` to your project (which has conflict)
4. Remove `neo4j maven dependency` from that project.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to have Neo4j and Lucene together in one jar, right.

Problem is, because Neo4j uses old Lucene version.

[Alessandro Negro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1986488/alessandro-negro) from [GraphAware](http://graphaware.com/) solved that problem and you can find his solution here - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-elasticsearch-tests

Comment: @RaufAgayev could you please show us your solution? Because I found problem with resources in web-inf directory, which could not be transformed by shade plugin.

Comment: 1. Add this to eclipse - https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar.
2. Use `mvn-install` and create `.jar`
3. Add that `.jar` to your project (which has conflict)
4. Remove neo4j maven dependency from that project.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the issue is that you are starting your database with a single jar. You need to be sure that in your classloader you are loading all the jar you need to start neo4j